# How can I make rounded corners on non-CSS3 browsers?

Tags: html, css

I know that I have to use images in this case, one per corner.

For example if I need a solid blue 4px border with 8px border radius around a given element,
and I have designed four images accordingly,

- top-left-corner.png
- top-right-corner.png
- bottom-left-corner.png
- bottom-right-corner.png

How should I implement this, if possible without using a table?

Comment: You just should not bother about it. IE users can live without rounded corners.

Comment: Well, yes, mainly IE, but there are probably also some less-known browsers concerned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would **not** use the css workarounds/hacks others have suggested here, I would keep to using images. Yes it's more fiddly to set up but it is cross-browser and robust. I have tried a number of these css workarounds and have found them to be unpredictable at best. They might work fine on some IE installs, but not on others (e.g completely crashing the browser). And worse we were unable to isolate why it worked fine on some installs, and not on others (and this is for the same IE version).

I would either: live without curved corners on IE, or use images. You can use nested divs:

```
<div class="top-left">
   <div class="top-right">
       <div class="bottom-left">
          <div class="bottom-right">

             ... content ...
          </div>
       </div> 
    <div>
 </div>
```

and in css you set the appropriated `background-image` for each class, something like this:

```
div.top-left { background: url('/top-left-corner.png') left top no-repeat; }
```

and set the border style for one of the divs too, e.g:

```
border: 4px solid #f00;
```

Comment: Thank you for your experience, nothing is worse than crashing the user's browser! And I think using nested divs is a clever idea - maybe it isn't semantically correct, but it looks reliable indeed and remains css compliant.

Comment: @Luc1245 - nested divs is basically how it's always been done prior to css3.

Comment: I've tried it, and that works fine with non-transparent images. But in my case I can see a rounded border _plus_ a square border at each corner; I'm using images whose pixels are all transparent except those ones that make up the curve of the corner, so that I don't have to make a different set of images if the background color of the underlying parent element changes. Please, do you have a solution in this case?

Comment: @Luc1245 - yes it wont work with images that have transparency. You have to set the image background to be the same as your page. It's a pain if you change the page background colour as you'll need to change your images, but unfortunately that's what you have to do. AFAIK there is no other way.

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried http://css3pie.com/about/ ? You don't have to use images in such a case...

Comment: Using images will make life harder in the long run, keeping it to css will mean you can handle design changes easier and keep it accessible :) +1

Comment: Thank you, very interesting resource! I didn't know about it. It doesn't require images to make rounded corners, that's a big advantage! But it's IE only and require that user security settings allow .htc files.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many links to this on google, just type rounded corners css and you should find something to help. Older techniques involved using something like a set of b tags above and below the box you want to round off and stting the margins to produce the radius you need, but it gets a bit involved and there are better antialiased solutions available.

Comment: Nice link, one can generate box images and download them, instead of having to design them oneself

Answer (score 1):

If you allow tables and some code, you can do it without images and easily switch colors:

http://spruce.flint.umich.edu/~jalarie/jaa_kcm.htm

Comment: Good tool! I will use it in the cases I can allow tables (and some spans in the corners). Nice that I can dynamically change colors.

Comment: There are many options with your generator, but I didn't find options like "border width" or "border color". Can I use it to make rounded corners with rounded borders like css border-radius does?