# Border-Radius not working in Email and Browser

Tags: html, email, css

I have been  designing a newsletter, and whilst the border-radius work on my localhost (showing all the rounds edges) - but it does not work when tested through sample email. I emailed myself using yahoo mail and Firefox, it came out with sharp edges. It does not work in outlook 2007 as well.

Anyone know how to solve this problem? I will appreciated your help.

Comment: Duplicate question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089248/email-newsletter-not-rendering-correctly/7089327#7089327

Answer (score 6):

It will never work in outlook 2007 as that uses word as the renderer, which doesn't support most css.

For firefox, you need to add the `-moz-` prefix, please ensure you have done that.

If not, post your css and firefox version.

Comment: Thanks for your tip - will add that now. Besides adding the 'moz-' to allow it display on Firefox, it there any other simpler method for creating round edges which can display on outlook?  I used a code and it was too long, so some here recommened I use border-radius. It turns out not to work on outlook :-(

Comment: the only thing you can do is images, this is best for emails as it means it will work in every image email client. web based email clients like yahoo and gmail just use the browser as the rendering client.

Comment: Thanks again, that looks like the only option now. Cheers anyway.

Answer (score 4):

I do not think that Outlook 2007 support the `border-radius` property, so it is probably normal if it does not display rounded corners. If you are looking for a workaround, I suggest you to have a look at this question: [How can I make rounded corners on non-CSS3 browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355493/how-can-i-make-rounded-corners-on-non-css3-browsers)

For the CSS in modern browsers, currently you need to prefix certain proprties, for example:

```
.withRoundedCorners {
    border-radius: 5px;        // Standard
    moz-border-radius: 5px;    // Firefox
    khtml-border-radius: 5px;  // 
    o-border-radius: 5px;      // Opera
    webkit-border-radius: 5px; // Safari
    ms-border-radius: 5px;     // Internet Explorer 9+
}
```

I know it's boring... But it's temporary, in the future only `border-radius` will be required.

Comment: I will use this when working on a browser. For now, I'll focus on outlook - that's what our target clients use. Cheers for the tips.

Comment: what about outlook/hotmail in application of windows?

Answer (score 1):

Newsletters in email campaign tools like (outlook, gmail, hotmail) has less CSS support. Moreover, border-radius is supported for web browsers not for email clients.

It is better to use  for background images, pure images, gradients, round corners and 3d related stuff instead of using CSS styling.

See this reference: [Campaign Monitor](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)

This reference shows which CSS property is supported by different email clients.

See other references: [Email newsletter not rendering correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089248/email-newsletter-not-rendering-correctly/7089327#7089327)